# how to deploy nodejs on aws with opsWorks?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using opsWorks, and created a nodejs application on ec2.

I want to be able to create a ec2 machine that will run on opsWorks deploy, but all i can do is make a EC2 machine that have nodejs installed. 
CHEF seams complicated for the simple thing i want to do.

anyone did it ? i want EC2 machine :
1. nodejs installed
2. git clone 
3. npm forever installed
4. npm log4js + mongoose installed

anyone did it ? whats the best way to do it ?

Comment: All of the answers are terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using OpsWorks is relatively simple, and you can probably just use the default Node set up. Check out [Has anyone been successful deploying a node (express) app with Amazon OpsWorks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986794/has-anyone-been-successful-deploying-a-node-express-app-with-amazon-opsworks) for some things to remember.

If you do it properly, OpsWorks will start your Node app for you. (most likely your filename is wrong).

As well, getting the packages you want installed is easy enough by just adding them into your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried elastic beanstalk for Node.js? It provide preconfigured container for Node.js.

Comment: well, 

someone here at work investigated it , and its too complicated , so that's why i am working with opsWorks.

Comment: @IdanHen would be interesting to hear details of why elastic beanstalk could be too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed nodejs application using Opsworks recently. I encountered similar problems and I documented the solution [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/jalquisola/2e78b9f1c04a862e8ba1).